# PHP: Generate png from text on the fly

Tags: php, png, gd

I wrote this function to create png file from text :

```
function pngfromtext($text){
    $fontsize = 5;
    $width = imagefontwidth($fontsize)* strlen($text);
    $height = imagefontheight($fontsize);

    $img = imagecreate($width, $height);

    // Transparent background
    $black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $black);

    // Red text
    $red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    imagestring($img, $fontsize, 0, 0, $text, $red);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
}
```

I put codes to `functions.php` file, When use this function in another page I get this error:

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ..\functions.php on line 58
�PNG  IHDRZ^%JPLTE����ٟ�tRNS@��f�IDAT�c` Hȱ�7�H��'��`c��s�����i��$���Hl`8��Ɛ�� ��#�c��p�� q�3f�òm�� �g�ـ�6fF ���h�bc�sXd4c�A4����?|�¦����r+���!IEND�B`�
```

What is wrong?

Comment: make sure you are not outputting anything (echo/var_dump etc.) prior to setting the header

Comment: You might have whitespace somewhere outside `<?php ?>` tags, or there might be a warning/notice being generated somewhere. Show the code in line 58 of functions.php, if that doesn't help, observe the request/response in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what specific output is sent before the PNG header.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy there isn't any output

Comment: @DCoder all whitespace removed but no chance.

Comment: What is in line 58? Did you look at the request with Fiddler?

Comment: @DCoder line 58 is: header('Content-type: image/png');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multiple  header in on page.

Answer (score 2):

Set the header at the point where you know that your output is going to be an image. This means set this statement

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

at the beginning of your php script.

There is also a possibility that the header-command was already executed before this point here.

Comment: it is a function and i cant use header at the top of script

Answer (score 1):

before `header('Content-type: image/png');` put `ob_clean();`
that cleans the response object so you can add the headers again

Comment: Could be a very dirty solution, because we don't know what comes before his function. There could also be a framework which sets some sort of complex headers...

Comment: I know but if it uses a framework its **really** hard to fix it so this is the quick and dirty way, yes

Comment: That depends on the framework. The problem with this answer is it only fixes the symptom, not the bug in the code.